# Change line selection display in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, select, line

can someone help me with a MapInfo query. Is it possible to change the display MapInfo uses when selecting lines? Atm I can be often difficult to see selected lines easily as the lines I am using are red and when selected there is slight red hashing around the edges. Would it be possible for a line to change color when selected, so it is easily distinguishable from other lines around it?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1):

Goto Options > Preferences > Styles.

here you can set the styles you would like to use for your highlighting.

Peter